# Keras Scratch Graph Error - Why does this error happen?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to training mobilenet-unet on a small dataset. But when start training, my model get an keras scratch graph error. This is the second time, I got this error. I am very confused why this error happens. This is error message.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVTK1.png)

Could anyone explain why this error happens? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please do not include errors as images but as text in your questions (images are not searchable or text can be copied from them).

Comment: Also keras_scratch_graph is not an error, the error is above that and its clearly OOM (out of memory).

Comment: oh... thank you. I will not includes errors as images anymore.

Comment: how do you know that it is OOM?

Comment: Its literally there in your traceback "OOM when allocating tensor with shape". Also you can just edit the question and put the traceback as text.